# propagate scroll event to waterfall-tall core header panel

Tags: scroll, transition, polymer, waterfall

I am trying to replicate this demo:

https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/grid.html

I want to use a waterfall-tall header panel instead. If I just change the mode of the scroll header panel, it doesn't collapse because the scrollable div is not the one expected.

Which would be the best way to have this demo working in the same way with a waterfall-tall header?

I tried having the animated pages scrollable instead but the hero transition is then messed up.

Best,
Nicolas

Comment: I think you should have the `core-animated-pages` wrap the `core-header-panel`, and then use the animated pages to switch between a list and a detail view.

Comment: I can not get it to work, do you have a demo by any chance? I basically want to share a toolbar between animated pages, but still want to be able to user the waterfall effect on the toolbar. The animation to go full screen should also work well. Thanks